# Split string via remembered Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var str="java+script+regex";
```

now i want to split the regex by `+` symbol only when `+` comes after word java.

So when i try

```
str.split(/java(\+)/)
```

then it splits the string using java+.So how can i split it using the `+` which comes after word java getting the result `["java","script+regex"]`

Comment: since look behind is not supported in javascript I don't think it is possible

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Possible but pain in the ass: reverse, split with lookahead `/\+(?=avaj)/`, reverse the resultant array and each member string :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split captures:

```
 "java+script+regex".split(/(java)\+/)
```

which gives you

```
["", "java", "script+regex"]
```

or `match`:

```
"java+script+regex".match(/(java)(?:\+)(.+)/).slice(1)
["java", "script+regex"]
```

or `replace`:

```
"java+script+regex+java+chrome".replace(/(java)\+/g, "$1@").split("@")
["java", "script+regex+java", "chrome"]
```

[This post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) shows different ways to emulate lookbehinds in javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately your first way is also splitting the array by + which is preceded by java and your second way is only splitting by first occurrence of java http://jsfiddle.net/gk8t7/16/

Comment: @Ankit Then use `str.split(/\+?(java)\+/)`.

Comment: @VisioN same problem as with this answer's first method http://jsfiddle.net/gk8t7/17/

Comment: @Ankit What do you expect as a result then?

Comment: @VisioN in fiddle `[java,script+regex+java,chrome]` but i am getting `[java,script+regex,java,chrome]`

Comment: @Ankit In fiddle you have: `[java,script+regex,java,chrome]`.

Comment: yes that could be a way and relying on @ sounds safe to me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this

```
var n=(" "+str).split(/(?=java[+])/)
               .join("java")
               .split(/java[+]/);
```

Comment: You should add another `.reverse`in the end.

Comment: Not even in groups? You're getting `["regex+script", "java"]` when it would be intuitive to get `["java", "script+regex"]`